# Implementation of Interbase password hashing algorithm in Objective-C/C

Tags: objective-c, c, hash, passwords, interbase

We have used Interbase/Firebird for many years, and have adopted the password hashing from the interbase security database as a convenient standard for some non-critical encryption uses.

Subsequently, we've built a suite of XML web services, and use the same hashing algorithm to encrypt certain data elements before transmitting them.  We've implemented ports of the algorithm in Delphi and in Java, over the years, though the programmers who successfully made those ports work are no longer available.

We now are looking at consuming our web services from iOS apps (being built by contractors), and need to port the same encryption algorithm to Objective-C.

I've spent time googling, and found some old forum posts that indicate that the original algorithm is the Crypt function from Unix.  However, there seem to be many implementations of Unix functions called Crypt, and it's not clear which, if any, might fit the bill.

I know that we should be able to provide our contractors with the implementation in Objective-C or plain C, and they ought to be able to use it.

Can anyone point me to a C/Objective-C implementation of the original Interbase password hashing algorithm?

I can provide any further information, if I've left anything out.

Comment: i just googled a bit. But i also cannot find any firebird hashing function. Do you have tech. specs how the hashing must be done? Is it not SHA-1 from firebird 2.0+?

Comment: My understanding of cryptography is pretty minimal, so I hope I'm adding useful information.

I believe it uses a rotation hash, which I have seen described as being similar the WW2 enigma machine.

I also see from the source code in Java, that it uses an initial key of '9z', and that it runs the string to be encrypted through the encryption process twice.

I'm not sure that I can provide many more details, but will try to answer further questions.

I believe that this is a different hashing algorithm than is used by Firebird 2.0+.  This is the legacy system from Interbase, in the 90s.

Comment: After more searching, using the Wayback Machine (web.archive.org), I was able to find a copy of unixpass.zip by Gerard Perreault.  It contains C source for the Interbase User Password encryption mechanism, which is exactly what I needed.